# Getting all methods inside a script file

Tags: c#, ruby, ironruby

After executing this code:

```
    var runtime = IronRuby.Ruby.CreateRuntime();
    var engine = IronRuby.Ruby.CreateEngine();
    var scrope = engine.CreateScope();
    engine.ExecuteFile("libtest.rb");
```

How can I get all the methods of a ruby class in c# code?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense, can you clarify? In Ruby, there are no methods inside files. All methods are inside modules or classes. From Ruby, you can simply call for example `Module#instance_methods` to get all instance methods of a module, and of course you can call that same method from C# as well.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didnt know all methods had to be inside a class or a module, I edited my question, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you can do it from C# http://github.com/casualjim/ironrubymvc/blob/master/IronRubyMvc/Core/RubyEngine.cs#L178

If you define methods without having them in a class they should get added to the Object class

Answer (score 2):

I haven't figured everything out yet, but here's a start:

```
using System;
using IronRuby;
using Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting;

class IronRubyReflection
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var engine = Ruby.CreateEngine();
        var scope = engine.ExecuteFile("libtest.rb");
        dynamic globals = engine.Runtime.Globals;

        var klass = globals.Klass;
        var klass_s = klass.GetOrCreateSingletonClass();
        var modul = globals.Modul;
        var modul_s = modul.GetOrCreateSingletonClass();

        Console.WriteLine(
            scope.GetVariable<IronRuby.Builtins.RubyMethod>(
                "method_in_the_global_object").Name);

        Action<string, IronRuby.Builtins.RubyModule,
            IronRuby.Runtime.Calls.RubyMemberInfo> classprinter =
                (n, k, i) => { Console.WriteLine(n, k, i); };

        klass.ForEachMember(false,
            IronRuby.Runtime.RubyMethodAttributes.Default, classprinter);
        klass_s.ForEachMember(false,
            IronRuby.Runtime.RubyMethodAttributes.Default, classprinter);
        modul.ForEachMember(false,
            IronRuby.Runtime.RubyMethodAttributes.Default, classprinter);
        modul_s.ForEachMember(false,
            IronRuby.Runtime.RubyMethodAttributes.Default, classprinter);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Forgive my style, I don't actually know C#.

This is my `libtest.rb`:

```
def method_in_the_global_object; end

class Klass
  def instance_method_in_class; end
  def self.class_method; end
end

class Modul
  def instance_method_in_module; end
  def self.module_method; end
end

local = Object.new
def local.singleton_meth; end

@instance = Object.new
def @instance.singleton_meth; end

$global = Object.new
def $global.singleton_meth; end
```

And this is the output:

```
method_in_the_global_object
instance_method_in_class
class_method
Equals
ReferenceEquals
allocate
clr_constructor
clr_ctor
clr_new
new
superclass
instance_method_in_module
module_method
Equals
ReferenceEquals
allocate
clr_constructor
clr_ctor
clr_new
new
superclass
```